# Save resources dialog

Tags: eclipse-rcp

My RCP application contains a custom editor. When I try to close this application the "Save resources" dialog is appearing with the list of duty editors:

How to invoke it programmically?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call IWorkbenchPage.saveAllEditors()